# Is there a way to call an Arrow Function just after it has been declared?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Sometimes I want to assign a variable the result of an Arrow function, but if I assign the Arrow Function to that variable it get the function and not the return of that Function as is obvious.

```
let theNumber2 = ()=>{return 2};
```

`theNumber2` will contain the function and only if I do `theNumber2()` I will get returned 2.

Is there a way to do something like this to get directly the return of the arrow function? For example:

```
let theNumber2 = ()=>{return 2}(); // Note the () at the final
```

Does there exist something to do that? I mean, to assign the arrow function called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap in parenthesis and call the function.

```js
let theNumber2 = (() => { return 2; })();

console.log(theNumber2);
```

Comment: Side note: `let theNumber2 = (() => 2)();` ;-)

Comment: mmm, if value of "2" changes between declaration of `theNumber2` and `console.log(theNumber2)`, it will still show `2` right?

Comment: @Hammerbot yes it will still show 2

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would prefer the return statement.The way you wrote it its smaller however in a quick glance if someone looked at the code they might got confused

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about it!. I need 9 min to make this the correct answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis - The concise form is **very** widely-used. Consider: `result = original.map(x => x.foo);` Getting used to `=>` not followed by `{` meaning it's returning what follows is going to be important. :-)

Comment: @Hammerbot - `let x = 2; let theNumber2 = (() => x)(); x = 3; console.log(theNumber2);` will still show `2` for the same reason this still shows `2`: `let x = 2; let y = x; x = 3; console.log(y);` The **value** is returned, with no enduring link to where that value came from.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  thanks for the reply :).I use the same form as you .What I say is that  if I read it as a newbie ,I am not sure I would have figured out what this code does from the first glance

Comment: @ManosKounelakis but you only need to learn what `() => 2` does once. If we start avoiding the more convenient syntax because somebody who never encountered it would not spend the 30 seconds needed to understand it for the rest of their lives, then we should just stop all progress and never add any language features to anything ever. Because there would always be newbies. Heck, we were all newbies. Yet we not only manage to push through the new development but actually push for them. The arrow-function shorthand was introduced *because* people wanted it and was more convenient.

Comment: @vlaz, *" ... we were all newbies ..."* o_O

Comment: @NinaScholz weren't we? I don't know of a single person who was born with the entire knowledge for programming in their brains. Yet we learned and started using more advanced contructs and teaching others so they can do the same.